# Jquery form field value

Tags: jquery, html

How can I the HTML string `<br>` from this HTML FORM pass to the DIV using Jquery?

HTML FORM is:

```
<form action="" id="submit_wall" name="submit_wall" method="post">
<textarea cols="50" rows="5" id="message_wall"></textarea>
<button type="submit" id="fst" class="cfst">send</button>
</form>

 <div id="wall"></div>
 <div class="msg"></div>
```

Jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
$("form#submit_wall").submit(function() {
var message_wall = $('#message_wall').attr('value');

$("div#wall").append('<div class=msg>'+ message_wall +'</div>');
return false; 
});
});
```

I'm trying using .html() but I keep getting error message.

Comment: Can you add the error you are getting. Also your HTML does not reference a div with ID "Wall".

Comment: There is no attribute of "value" for the textarea. What are you trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example from [learningjquery.com](http://www.learningjquery.com/2006/11/really-simple-live-comment-preview)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#comment').one('focus',function() {
 $('#comment').parent().after('<div id="preview-box"><div class="comment-by">Live Comment Preview</div><div id="live-preview"></div></div>');
  });
  var $comment = ''; // that's two single quotation-marks at the end
  $('#comment').keyup(function() {
 $comment = $(this).val();
 $comment = $comment.replace(/\n/g, "<br />").replace(/\n\n+/g, '<br /><br />').replace(/(<\/?)script/g,"$1noscript");
 $('#live-preview').html( $comment );
  });
});
```

Which is very close of what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks Keyne! This example is very helpful.

Comment: Another quick way is to use `white-space: pre;` in the CSS for the div being appended to. Then you don't have to do <br> replacements. Then your original code should produce desired result.

Answer (score 0):

**First**, as durilai commented, there is no `div` with an ID of `wall`, which means that even if your submit handler is working, `append` isn't going to append since there's nothing to append to.

**Second**, even though you said `action=""` on the form, the form will still submit and cause what looks like a page reload because you are not preventing the default action in your submit handler. One quick fix is to add `return false;` as the last line of the handler. Another fix is to rewrite it like:

```
$("form#submit_wall").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    $("div#wall").append("<div class='msg'>"+ $("#message_wall").val() + "</div>");
});
```

Comment: There are two DIV's in the HTML code but I forgot to put it in my question. Ok, now I edit it.

I tried with 'var message_wall = $('#message_wall').val();' but there is no html line break '<br>' in the DIV as it is in the form text field.